# String intersection in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, intersection, in-operator

This is my code:

```
keyinput = input() # I type 'appleandgold'

B = 'appleblue'

if keyinput in B: # Should actually be keyinput "intersects" B   
     print(keyinput) # Should print intersection
```

The result (printed value) for `keyinput = 'appleandgold'` and `B = 'appleblue'` should be `'apple'`, but I can only get it to work for `keyinput = 'apple'`.

Comment: `how i print results` add code for it]

Comment: So you're looking for a way to find the longest common substring? By the way, `type` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Your code is syntactically wrong (`If`?), contains a redundant line (`type` doesn't do what you appear to think it does) and will fail anyway (`"appleandgold"` *isn't* `in "appleblue"`).

Comment: how code look like i want result of IF .. IN .. statment?

Comment: You need to better define your question. Are you looking for the longest common substring of both words? Check this link out for a solution.
http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_longest_common_substring_lcs_algorithm_generalized_suffix_tree.php

Comment: Ty anyway do they have way to print result of (IF .. IN ..) it self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this without importing any module :

```
s1='appleandgold'
s2='appleblue'

track=[]
for k in range(len(s1)):
    if k!=0:
        for ka in range(0,len(s1),k):
            if s1[ka:ka+k] in s2:
                track.append((len(s1[ka:ka+k]),s1[ka:ka+k]))
print(max(track)[1])
```

output:

```
apple
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your looking for the longest common substring. The standard library contains the `difflib` module for that:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

keyinput = input()  # I type "appleandgold"

B = "appleblue"

match = SequenceMatcher(a=keyinput, b=B).find_longest_match(
    0,
    len(keyinput),
    0,
    len(B),
)
print(keyinput[match.a:match.a+match.size])  # prints "apple"
```

Comment: thk this work  now i can use output of (apple) to select from database with pymysql